# Query timeout in Neo4j 3.0.6

Tags: neo4j

It looks like previously working approach is deprecated now:

```
unsupported.dbms.executiontime_limit.enabled=true
unsupported.dbms.executiontime_limit.time=1s
```

According to the [documentation](http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/reference/) new variables are responsible for timeouts handling:

```
dbms.transaction.timeout
dbms.transaction_timeout
```

At the same time the new variables look related to the transactions.

The new timeout variables look not working. They were set in the neo4j.conf as follows:

```
dbms.transaction_timeout=5s
dbms.transaction.timeout=5s
```

Slow cypher query isn't terminated.

Then the Neo4j plugin was added to model a slow query with transaction:

```
    @Procedure("test.slowQuery")
    public Stream<Res> slowQuery(@Name("delay") Number Delay )
    {
        ArrayList<Res> res = new ArrayList<>();

        try ( Transaction tx = db.beginTx() ){
            Thread.sleep(Delay.intValue(), 0);
            tx.success();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        return res.stream();
    }
```

The function served by the plugin is executed with neoism Golang package. And the timeout isn't triggered as well.

Answer (score 0):

The timeout is only honored if your procedure code invokes either operations on the graph like reading nodes and rels or explicitly checks if the current transaction is marked as terminate.

For the later, see https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/blob/master/src/main/java/apoc/util/Utils.java#L41-L51 as example.

Comment: Thank you @Stefan for the tip. But I still can't get the timeout triggering. The plugin function was refactored - [gist](https://gist.github.com/mahinko/2ffd22f6a5e2eaa0f615e66729900846). I tried different variants including the transaction wrapper as in the initial attempt. 

And do I understand correctly, that there is no way to set the execution timeout for a cypher query executed with REST API any more?

Comment: however `apoc.util.sleep` works as expected, just verified this on a 3.1.0-beta1. For query specific timeouts use `apoc.cypher.runTimeboxed`.

Comment: yes the sleeping works and and was working with my  original approach. The sleeping was used to trigger the timeout. Using the `apoc.cypher.runTimeboxed` may be a solution but I'm wondering if it is possible to achieve the timeout triggering with Neo4j native functionality. Like it was possible previously with `dbms.executiontime_limit.enabled=true`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation the transaction guard is interested in orphaned transactions only.

> The server guards against orphaned transactions by using a timeout. If there are no requests for a given transaction within the timeout period, the server will roll it back. You can configure the timeout in the server configuration, by setting dbms.transaction_timeout to the number of seconds before timeout. The default timeout is 60 seconds.

I've not found a way how to trigger timeout for a query which isn't orphaned with a native functionality.

@StefanArmbruster pointed a good direction. The timeout triggering functionality can be got with creating a wrapper function in Neo4j plugin like it is made in [apoc](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/blob/1cedb566318f22efd0a838326f97670e32c87f4b/src/main/java/apoc/cypher/Cypher.java#L374).